# PHP CMS to Serve Clojurescript Frontend

Tags: php, cms

my goal is to build a small flat renting portal (two locations, 7 flats total, semiautomatic booking system)… nothing that requires scalability or anything too fancy but I'm facing three challenges:

1. I would love to use Clojurescript for the frontend.
2. My non-techy client must be able to maintain the site without constant intervention from my side. So I need some kind of CMS in order to let him add pictures to galleries, update prices and tweak text (graphical editor is a requirement). I would be ok with implementing  part of this myself.
3. I have to tap into a google calendar in order to check the availability of the apartments (only reading access)… this can only sensibly be done within the backend I suppose.
4. For the backend I am limited to the use of PHP since this will have to run on a shared hosting service and node.js simply won't work the way I hoped it would.

Do you have any ideas as to where I might go for here? Does anyone have experience using Clojurescript in tandem with a PHP-based backend? Would you deem headless WordPress a viable option for my use case?

Many thanks!

Oliver

(Please tell me if I'D better ask my question on another site like stachoverflow)

Comment: You *might* find a suitable CMS at http://cmsmatrix.org/   You might also find a complete, ready built app, if you ask for that

Comment: Thanks… I wasn't aware of that site. As an afterthought I might add that since I'm planning on using the Reagent framwork in Clojurescript which is basically an adaptation of React, a headless CMS that plays well with React should be a good fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the record: I've ended up using [Directus](https://directus.io/) as headless CMS, which offers perfect Database transparency and a solid API. I stumbled across ti on cmsmatrix.org recommended by Mawg… many thanks for that pointer.